# How to add token from shared preferences to an interceptor

Tags: java, android, jwt, retrofit

After I authenticate and get JWT in header I want to add token to every request sent from person logged in with this token. 
But I don't know how to pass token from shared preferences to my Api client class.

I tried defining sharedPref object, but it needs Context to use .getSharedPreferences method.

This is how I retrieve and save token from authentication endpoint: (*this is in loginActivity class*)

```
private void login() {

        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
        loginRequest.setUsername(usernameLog.getText().toString().trim());
        loginRequest.setPassword(passwordLog.getText().toString().trim());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Call<Void> loginResponseCall = ApiClient.getUserService().login(loginRequest);
        loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    token = response.headers().get("Authorization");

                    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("logged", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isLogged", true);
                    editor.putString("token", token);
                    editor.apply();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User logged in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User failed logging in: " + t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is my ApiClient class, where I'm trying to use token saved from Shared Preferences.

```
    public class ApiClient {
    
        private static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
    
            HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    
            OkHttpClient client =  new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                        Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("Authorization", TOKEN) 

 
//    Instead of "TOKEN" I need to somehow pass
//
//    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("logged", MODE_PRIVATE);
//    preferences.getString("token", "");

 
                                .build();
                        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                    })
                    .build();
    
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.60:8080/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
    
            return retrofit;
        }
    
        public static UserService getUserService() {
            UserService userService = getRetrofit().create(UserService.class);
    
            return userService;
        }
    }
```

When I hard code it, it works. But It needs to pass token dynamically depending on which user is logged in.

Comment: make ```getRetrofit``` to have context as a parameter like ```getRetrofit(Context context)``` and when you call this static method from fragment or activity pass ```getContext()``` or ```getApplicationContext()``` respectively

Comment: I knew that the problem is trivial. Thank you very much. I passed Context as a parameter and It works now.